# Managing multiple postgres versions on CentOS

Tags: centos, postgresql

I have the following packages installed with `yum`:

```
Installed Packages
postgresql92.x86_64                                                                                                  9.2.24-1.65.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql92-libs.x86_64                                                                                             9.2.24-1.65.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql92-server.x86_64                                                                                           9.2.24-1.65.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql92-server-compat.x86_64                                                                                    9.2.24-1.65.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql95.x86_64                                                                                                  9.5.10-1.77.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql95-libs.x86_64                                                                                             9.5.10-1.77.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
postgresql95-server.x86_64                                                                                           9.5.10-1.77.amzn1                                                                                   @amzn-updates
```

But I can't seem to control them individually:

```
/home/ec2-user$ sudo service postgresql95 stop
Stopping postgresql95 service:                             [  OK  ]
/home/ec2-user$ sudo service postgresql95 status
postmaster (pid  43442) is running...
/home/ec2-user$ sudo service postgresql92 status
postmaster (pid  43442) is running...
```

Why are they having the same pid?

Also I only have 1 configuration file, located in `/var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Can you specify how did you create the instances ? The init phase

Comment: Did you follow : https://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/82-Running-more-than-one-9.4-9.3-instance-in-parallel-on-RHEL-7.html

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I just do `service postgresql start` after installing 92. Then i install 95 and the above is the output

Comment: The tutorial is not for CentOS, it doesn't have `systemd` and I can't find 2 `postgresql-*.service`

Comment: Actually it does use systemd at the end. What version of CentOS are you using ?

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET i meant CentOS doesn't have systemd. It also uses `service` instead of `systemctl`. I'm using `Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03` which is CentOS I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go to this [page](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) and download the appropriate packages for CentOS 6 (as you mentionned using service and not systemd)

Once setup you can install both `postgresql92-server` and `postgresql95-server` through the commend `yum install postgresql92-server postgresql95-server`.

You have to manually init the databases like the following `service postgresql-9.2 initdb` and `service postgresql-9.5 initdb`. That will create 2 different databases directories in `/var/lib/pgsql`, `9.2` and `9.5` and initialize a database inside of each data subdirectory.

Once this is done you can start each instance with its own service comand `service postgresql-9.2 start` and `service postgresql-9.5 start`. But not both at the same time as they're using the same 5432 port.

9.2 port can be edited in `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2` with variable PGPORT
9.5 port can be edited in `/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/postgresql.conf` with the variable port. So you can use both instances at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working. Both 92 and 95 uses the `PGPORT` specified in `/etc/init.d/postgresql9*`, so it seems like the port in `postgresql.conf` gets overridden?

Comment: From this comment I guess you are using a different postgresql package, so yes the config file might be different. But as you said, the idea is the same